# Laravel Schema Builder Update Default Value

Tags: laravel, migration, database-schema, eloquent

Trying to setup a migration that will make my already existing "active" field have a default value of "1".

I see in the docs I can use something like:

```
$table->integer('active')->default(1);
```

But I tried this in my migration with no success, I guess because the field already exists. Is there a way to correctly manage existing fields using the schema builder?

My current migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('scores', function($table){
        $table->integer('active')->default(1);
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

From what I've read so far, this can't be done with the query builder. But when I try to run a raw query:

```
DB::query("ALTER TABLE `scores` CHANGE COLUMN `active` `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';");
```

I'm getting a "method 'query' does not exist error", so I'm guessing this method name was changed I just can't find what it was changed to

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like DB::query() was changed to DB::statement()

This did the trick:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `scores` CHANGE COLUMN `active` `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';");
```

Comment: Since you are not changing the name of the column, instead of CHANGE COLUMN you can use MODIFY COLUMN and omit the second active in your statement. New statement as follows: DB::statement("ALTER TABLE scores MODIFY COLUMN active int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1';");` stackoverflow.com/a/14767467/788445